# How to use GDAL in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, gdal

How to used GDAL library(Written in C++) Want to use in my project. My project in swift language.

[image]

Comment: try this: http://www.hurtsdevelopment.com/blog/uncategorized/gdal-on-ios-it-works/

Answer (score 0):

Use Anaconda to install the library(from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal). Then apply the necessary steps to use the library in your IDE.